# Join one of any threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

In my Java program, I will launch two Threads simultaneously. I want for my program to join() on either one of two threads's completion without waiting for both threads to complete. In other words, if thread A finishes before thread B, I want the main thread to join thread A and resume the main thread without waiting for Thread B to finish and vice versa.

Which of those Java classes that allows me to do this?

Comment: Instead of making your own Threads, create an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), and pass your tasks to its [invokeAny](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAny-java.util.Collection-) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to accomplish that is with a [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), by having the main thread wait for its count to reach zero, and having the two threads each decrease the count (the initial value of the count would be 1 in this case).

Comment: I used the CountDownLatch in my program and it worked flawlessly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] atrgs){
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    while(t1.isAlive()&&t2.isAlive()){

    }
    System.out.println("main resumes");

}
```

Comment: But using while loop to spin the main thread to achieve thread synchronization is not a valid thread synchronization technique. It seems like it would require three threads under the hood, two threads for each thread and one thread for while loop to check on both threads.

Comment: Even in the absence of while loop there will be 3 threads only. However using latches would be preferable as latch.await() is meant for that only. I just wanted to shared simpler approach if in case you don't want to use Count down latches.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, any class in Java allows you to do that since an object of any class can be used as a monitor for waiting a notification. Just create an object, call `wait()` on it and make your threads notify on this object when finished:

```
private class Foo implements Runnable {
    private final int id;
    private final Object monitor;
    public Foo(int id, Object monitor) {
        this.id = id;
        this.monitor = monitor;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep((long)(Math.random() * 10000));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        System.out.println(id + " finished");
        synchronized (monitor) {
            monitor.notify();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final Object monitor = new Object();
    synchronized (monitor) {
        new Thread(new Foo(1, monitor)).start();
        new Thread(new Foo(2, monitor)).start();
        System.out.println("Main goes to sleep");
        monitor.wait();
    }
    System.out.println("Main is running");
}
```

The first notification will unblock the main thread and it will continue running.

I would say that this is a classic solution for your problem, though the solution that @AR.3 suggested will be less wordy and will surely work. I just wanted to show that even a simple monitor object is enough to do what you want.

Comment: That's an interesting approach to the problem. I used CountDownLatch because like you said, it is less wordy than this solution but thank you for sharing this.